# Running doctests from Pydev?

Tags: pydev, doctest

Is there any straightforward way or should I use an external tool like [Nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose)?

Comment: But the real question is: how to run in-place doctest-code in PyDev (i.e. "select-and-execute"), like PyCharm does? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240835/how-do-i-run-doctests-with-pycharm

Answer (score 7):

[Pydev 1.6.4 provides support](http://pydev.blogspot.com/2010/12/improved-unittest-support-in-pydev.html) for a [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) test runner.

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pyunit.html describes how to configure the nose test runner.

To run doc tests, you'll need to specify the `--with-doctest` switch for the nose runner.

Answer (score 2):

Xv's answer is correct, unless you have tests that are in external files (like testable specifications) in which case you should add the `doctest-extension=txt` switch (substituting txt for whatever your extension is).