# How do I run doctests with PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, doctest

In the PyCharm IDE, if I right-click on a function/method with a doctest, sometimes the right-click menu will give me the option: "**Run 'Doctest my_function_name'**" and sometimes the right-click menu, instead, only gives the option to run the whole file (NOT as a doctest).

What determines when it will give the "run doctest" option and when it will not?  Is there a way to force it one way or the other?

Comment: I haven't found an answer to this, yet, but it appears that certain imports within the file are what cause the problem to come up.  So I sometimes can avoid the issue restructuring things so that the function I'm testing is moved to another module.  Splitting things up into different modules often results in cleaner, more-reusable code anyway, so it's not a horrible workaround... but still, it would be better if PyCharm would just work consistently.  Hopefully jetbrains will fix the issue eventually.

Comment: On a related note, I upgraded to PyCharm 4.5 yesterday, and haven't seen the issue again, so far.  But it's only been 2 days, so it doesn't really mean that the problem is fixed.  But I'm hopeful :)

Comment: Hmm.. I'm currently using PyCharm 4.5 and still seeing the problem :(
Thanks for the tip about restructuring btw, I'll try that.

Comment: Not sure what causes it to give the option, but you can force it to run doctest by going to Run>Edit Configurations...>click the green +>Python tests>Doctests>Enter your script

Comment: I get the impression that the problem comes after importing sqlite3

Comment: I checked with the latest version of PyCharm (v5) and it works very well. I did a copy/paste with the doctest example from https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html into a new file and PyCharm recognized it and allowed me to "Run 'Doctest' factorial", returning the doctest results. If this still fails for you, I would suggest you to [raise a bug with PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).

Comment: Seems to work absolutely fine for my under PyCharm 5. Unless i don't have a doc in the function, but that is obvious I guess.

Comment: Best I can tell, if the cursor is positioned within the docstring of a method, and that docstring has `>>>` in it, then a right click will bring up the Run Doctest ... option. Right clicking with the mouse pointer over the docstring does not bring up the dialog if the cursor was not within in the docstring.

Is this different then the behavior that you see?

Comment: @Troy, I checked my answer below on a friend's system running `PyCharm` 4.5 and it applies to that version as well.

Comment: Also do not name the module as `test.py` and `doctest.py`, someone might make this mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Running a module (or the tests in it) in `PyCharm` is done via a [Run Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration.html). When you right click a module, `PyCharm` searches for an existing `Run Configuration` for that module. If a configuration is found (this can be due to a previous run, or a manual creation of a `Configuration`), `PyCharm` will only suggest to run that configuration.

For example, if a configuration of `module.py` was created to run its `doctests`, that is the option we'll see when right-clicking `module.py`. However, if no configuration is found, `PyCharm` suggests to run the module in different options, depending on the code in the module (run regularly, or run `doctests` / `unittests`). Once an option is chosen, `PyCharm` creates the respective, temporary, `Run Configuration`, implicitly. From here on, when right clicking the module, you'll only get the configuration that was created for that module.

**Important side note:** PyCharm saves up to 6 temporary (i.e., `Configurations` that were created via running a module) `Run Configurations`- 3 in "Python", i.e., scripts, and 3 in "Python Tests". This means that if you run `moduleA.py`, `moduleB.py`, `moduleC.py`, and then `moduleD.py`, the temporary `Configurations` in PyCharm will be `moduleB.py`, `moduleC.py`, and `moduleD.py`. The configuration of `moduleA.py` will be automatically deleted, unless explicitly saved.

This behaviour can be reproduced as following:

1. In `PyCharm`, create a new Python module: "temp"

2.Add the following to the module:

```
"""
    >>> print 3.14
    3.14
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

3. Right click on the doctest section gives the option to "Run 'Doctests in temp' "
4. Right click on the **main** section gives the option to "Run 'temp' "
5. Choosing anyone of the options, makes the other option disappear in subsequent runs. E.g., choosing to **run** the module will make the option to run **Doctests** disappear in subsequent runs, and vice versa.
   Going back to the first stage, where it was possible to choose between the two options, is possible by deleting the module's "Run configuration":

Run --> Edit configuration --> Locate the module's current configuration (usually highlighted) --> Click the "Minus" button (top left corner) --> Click "Apply" --> Click OK.
Now we are back at step 3.

(Reproduced in `PyCharm` 5.0 and 4.5)

### To summarize:

- If no `Run Configuration` is found, PyCharm suggests to run the module in any possible way (as a script, doctests, or unittests)
- If a `Run Configuration` is found, PyCharm only suggests that `Configuration`.
- If PyCharm isn't giving you the run option that you want, find the `Run Configuration` that is preventing it from giving you that option and **delete it**, or create a new one that will run the file, or method/function, the way you want.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to delete configurations, you can also hit the shortcut key for Run | Resume Program (F9 for me) to pop up a complete list of choices

Comment: Thanks for this. PyCharm is a great tool, but they sure do bury a lot of features in non-intuitive ways.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems that the main menu options `Run – Run …` and `Run – Debug …` are the canonical way to get all possible ways to run something. Why the right-click context menu doesn't have those two options is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

If the above *doesn't* work for you - make sure that your module is *not* named `doctest`; it will cause a conflict and therefore cause the exception.