# How to have PyCharm see a doctest specified by a `__doc__` assignment

Tags: python, pycharm, doctest

Consider the following doc containing doctests.

```py
def f(x):
   """
   Increments by one.
   >>> f(2)
   3
   """
   return x + 1
```

PyCharm's test runner ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240835/how-do-i-run-doctests-with-pycharm)) picks the doctest up.

But the following is not seen by PyCharm as a doctest (though it is seen by `pytest --doctest-modules -v` for example).

```py
f = lambda x: x + 1
f.__doc__ = """
Increments by one.
>>> f(2)
3
"""
```

Comment: I sense an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Silly thing to try: Try indenting the contents of the manually assigned docstring by one level (and maybe the close triple-quote line as well). I don't know what PyCharm does normally to find tests, but outside of module level docstrings, the contents can be assumed indented, and it's possible the functionality it's using to find/parse docstrings for tests has a problem with the tests aren't indented at all. Heck, in [the answer to the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980789/364696) the example has even the module-level doc string indented, which makes me suspicious.

Comment: Yes, @ShadowRanger; that seems to have worked. Why don't you make it an answer so I can assign it as the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66478049/how-to-have-pycharm-see-a-doctest-specified-by-a-doc-assignment?noredirect=1#comment117528274_66478049), it looks like PyCharm expects all the tests to be indented at least one level (even in [cases where it's the module level docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33980789/364696), which need not be indented at all, it seems to rely on that level of indentation). This is not a requirement of regular doctests (`python3 -mdoctest -v modulename.py` works just fine), but PyCharm's gotta be difficult.

Your manually assigned docstring has no indentation, and PyCharm appears to ignore it as a result. Changing it to:

```
f = lambda x: x + 1
f.__doc__ = """
    Increments by one.
    >>> f(2)
    3
    """
```

to make the string include one level of indentation seems to be enough to get PyCharm on board.